# Button using pygame_menu.events.CLOSE nonfunctional

Tags: python, events, pygame-menu

Though a button calling `pygame_menu.events.EXIT` works to close the whole Pygame program, one calling `pygame_menu.events.CLOSE` does not seem to do anything. (Edit: I also tried the menu `close()` method, but with the same result.) I would like it to close the menu, allowing the program to proceed using the input recorded by the menu.

Here is my minimum reproducible example:

```
import pygame
import pygame_menu

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))

menu = pygame_menu.Menu(
    'Hey',
    1000,
    700
)

menu.add.button(
    'Close',
    pygame_menu.events.CLOSE
)
menu.mainloop(screen)
```

The menu opens and the button appears, but clicking the button does nothing. What should I be doing differently?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think You don't close anything but rather hide or more like do not show it anymore for example if you `.blit` something from menu stop doing that when moving on

Comment: ok so I relooked and I don't see any function that would collect the data, for example add a function to the button that will actually do something

Comment: @Matiiss I have selectors with `onchange` collecting data. I'll see whether I can rewrite it.

What use is `events.CLOSE`, then?

Comment: honestly I have no idea. it seems to close events

Comment: @Matiiss That's a valid answer to my question, by the way.

Comment: what do You mean by valid and here are some sources about event in pygame: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html

Comment: I mean that you could post your first two comments as an answer.

Interesting. Is there a link between Pygame events and pygame_menu events?

Comment: oh, that is a bit strange. I know nothing about pygame_menu You should read their docs